# Add clicklistener to another activity on listview item?

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi guys i have created  a list view in my android app that loads values from a mysql database. How can i add an intent to another activity when i click on each item? I want to make the new activity with swipe tabs. Is this possible? Can anybody point me?

Comment: post your code and specify the problem.

Comment: set an onclicklistener on your list item. In this method create an intent, that points to a new Activity (which can contain anything - even a Tab view).  This is basic stuff, you should look at some tutorials.

Comment: I created a method with the onitemclicklistener but all the items have the same onclick method..

Comment: @KostasMatrix there is position param that you need to use which is th eindex of list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ClickListener with list and start activity with intent according to the position os list item clicked

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

   switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // Start activity 1 with intent
        break;
    case 1:
        // Start activity 2 with intent
        break;
    case 2:
        // Start activity 3 with intent
        break;

    }


 }
}
```

If you want to add Fragments on Runtime add fragments instead of Activity